# Visual studio test agent Compatible with Server 2016

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are trying to setup a test environment for TFS (on premise). Now we are haveing some troubles to get the Visual Studio Test Agent (2015 update 3) running on a new Server 2016 OS. Does someone know if these are compatible?

On this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents) there is not a mentioning of Server 2016.

Thanks

Comment: When I use a Server 2012 it is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Visual Studio Test Agent 2015 update3*  is also a part/tool of Visual Studio 2015.

However according to the supported operating system of **Tools for Visual Studio 2015**:

[image]

Windows Server 2016 is **not supported**. More details please refer to this link: *[Visual Studio 2015 System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs#a-idtools-a-tools-for-visual-studio-2015)*

If you want to run the test agent on a new Server 2016 OS.Suggest you to install Test Agents for Visual Studio 2017, you could download it [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Comment: After some trials it finally worked also on Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Server 2016 for the old Test Agents for Lab Management.

You should switch to the new build system introduced in TFS 2015 and the new cross platform Test Agent that is supported most places...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment#supported-scenarios